# Test class at %50

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm getting only 50% code coverage for this Test Class:

```
    /**
 * This class contains unit tests for validating the behavior of LeadConvertUtil
 *
 */
@isTest
public class Test_LeadConvertUtil{ 

    static testMethod void leadConvertTrigrTest() {
        //test.startTest();
        //Lead VPS Record Type
        // BEGIN:  S-444340, T-567488 - include Lead record type = 'IAA VPS Sales'
        List<RecordType> leadRecordTypes = [select Id, Name 
                                            from RecordType 
                                            where SobjectType = 'Lead' and Name='IAA VPS Sales']; 
        //Insert Test Lead
        Lead ldTst = new Lead();
        ldTst.FirstName = 'Lead1';
        ldTst.LastName = 'Lead';
        ldTst.email = 'user@testOrg.com';
        ldTst.Company = 'TestCorp';
        ldTst.Contract_Type__c = 'CFF';

        if(leadRecordTypes!=null && leadRecordTypes.size()>0){          
            ldTst.recordTypeId = leadRecordTypes.get(0).Id;         
        }

        ldTst.Lead_Stage__c = 'Account Activated';
        ldTst.Status ='Converted';

        insert ldTst;


        Account acct = new Account();
        acct.Name = 'Neil Account';
        insert acct;
    }   


    static testMethod void leadConvertUtilTest() {

        //Lead VPS Record Type
        // BEGIN:  S-444340, T-567488 - include Lead record type = 'IAA VPS Sales'
        List<RecordType> leadRecordTypes = [select Id, Name 
                                            from RecordType 
                                            where SobjectType = 'Lead' and Name='IAA VPS Sales'];

        //Insert Test Lead
        Lead ldTst = new Lead();
        ldTst.FirstName = 'Lead1';
        ldTst.LastName = 'Lead';
        ldTst.email = 'user@testOrg.com';
        ldTst.Company = 'TestCorp';
        ldTst.Contract_Type__c = 'CFF';

        //ldTst.RecordType.Name = 'IAA VPS Sales';

        if(leadRecordTypes!=null && leadRecordTypes.size()>0){          
            ldTst.recordTypeId = leadRecordTypes.get(0).Id;         
        }
        ldTst.Lead_Stage__c = 'Account Activated';
        ldTst.Status ='Converted';
        insert ldTst;

        LeadConvertUtil.convertLead(ldTst);

       //test.stopTest(); 

    }   
}
```

and it in line 34, but not sure how to add that part to the test class?

[image]

Comment: You have the same problem as before-- your try-catch block is covering the real error. In this case, Database.convertLead is throwing an exception that is caught and discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unit test should not be setting the Status to converted, but instead a non-converted status, so you can then convert the record in the utility class. You might also be getting errors in your utility class, but the try-catch block is hiding those errors. Off the top of my head, it looks like you'll need to start with the following code for your utility class:

```
public class LeadConvertUtil {

    public static void convertLead(Lead leadRcd) {
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(leadRcd.Id);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
        lc.setConvertedStatus('Converted');
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        Account convertedAccount = new Account(
            Id=lcr.getAccountId(), 
            Converted_Lead_ID__c=leadRcd.Id,
            RecordType=new RecordType(Name=leadRcd.Lead_Record_Type_Name__c)
        );
        Contact convertedContact = new Contact(
            Id=lcr.getContactId(),
            RecordType=new RecordType(Name=leadRcd.Lead_Record_Type_Name__c)
        );
        update new SObject[] { convertedAccount, convertedContact };
    }
}
```

From here, fix any errors that you encounter, and add error checking. Do not use try-catch blocks unless you absolutely need to.

One important thing to remember is that DML operations, by default, throw exceptions. Depending on how you're using this utility class, you will probably want to call it by way of try-catch on the outside, like this:

```
SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
try {
    LeadConvertUtil.convertLead(leadRecord);
} catch(DmlException e) {
    Database.rollback(sp);
}
```

From there, depending on the context, you'll want to add the errors to the page, or a log, or something.